# Removing a user defined object in a HashSet in Java

Tags: java, hashset

I have created a simple class called Idea with a HashSet of ColumnPositions(another class I created with just an x and y field) . The equals and hashcode method in ColumnPosition looks like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + x;
    result = prime * result + y;
    System.out.println("hashCode: " + result);
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof ColumnPosition) {
        ColumnPosition cp = (ColumnPosition) obj;
        if (cp.x != this.x || cp.y != this.y) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, when I go to test the Idea class and try to remove a ColumnPosition object within the HashSet of the Idea object. It doesn't work. What's wrong?? Thanks!

```
public void test_HashSetRemoveColumnPosition() {
    ColumnPosition column_03 = new ColumnPosition(0, 3);

    Set<ColumnPosition> columns = new HashSet<ColumnPosition>();
    columns.add(column_03);

    this.idea.getColumnPositions().add(column_03);
    assertEquals(1, columns.size());

    assertTrue(this.idea.getColumnPositions().remove(column_03)); // this is passing
    assertEquals(0, columns.size()); // this is failing because columns.size() still equals 1. WHAT?! How is this possible if the remove method returned true?
}
```

Comment: First problem: you're returning `true` when someone calls `equals` with any non-ColumnPosition object.

Comment: I think we'll need to see the source for `this.idea.unionColumnPositions(columns)` and `this.idea.getColumnPositions()`.

Comment: Next, take out the `unionColumnPositions` etc part - we have no idea what that does. Try just `columns.remove(column_03)` for example. I suspect that will work. Then you need to look at what `unionColumnPositions` does.

Comment: `columns` is local variable in your method and within `assertTrue(this.idea.getColumnPositions().remove(column_03));` method you are removing the element from instance variable referencing a `Set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `this.idea.getColumnPositions()` is the same object as `columns`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 hashsets: the local variable in your test and a field in your test class. They are not the same so when you remove from one, the other is not modified...